# How can I share data between components & pages in Next JS 13?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, next.js13

I'm currently working on implementing account user state sharing across all components and pages in my website application using Next.js and React Hook Context. However, whenever I attempt to access the data, it consistently returns a false value.

`src/layout.tsx`:

```
"use client";

import "./globals.css";
import Header from "./components/Header";
import Footer from "./components/Footer";

import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { usePathname, useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import AuthProvider from "./contexts/AuthContext";
import { useIsLogged } from "./hooks/IsLogged";

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  const [menu, setMenu] = useState(false);

  const path = usePathname();
  const router = useRouter();

  const { isLoggedIn } = useIsLogged();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isLoggedIn) {
      if (path === "/admin/login") {
        router.push("/admin/blog");
      }
    } else {
      if (path.includes("/admin")) {
        router.push("/admin/login");
      }
    }
  }, [isLoggedIn]);

  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={`${menu && "overflow-hidden sm:overflow-auto"}`}>
        <AuthProvider>
          <Header menu={menu} setMenu={setMenu} />
          {children}
          <Footer />
        </AuthProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

`/src/contexts/AuthContext.tsx`:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, createContext, ReactNode } from "react";
import { auth } from "@/services/firebase";

export const AuthContext = createContext(
  {} as {
    isLoggedIn: boolean;
    setLoggedIn: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>;
  },
);

export default function AuthProvider({ children }: { children: ReactNode }) {
  const [isLoggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => { // When Firebase Auth State Chage
      if (user) setLoggedIn(true);
    });
    return () => {
      unsubscribe();
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ isLoggedIn, setLoggedIn }}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

I'm utilizing Firebase Authentication for user authentication.

`/src/hooks/IsLogged.ts`:

```
import { useContext } from "react";
import { AuthContext } from "@/app/contexts/AuthContext";

export const useIsLogged = () => {
  const value = useContext(AuthContext);
  return value;
};
```

Comment: In `/src/hooks/IsLogged.ts`, what if you changed the `return value` line to `return value.isLoggedIn`?

Comment: I need the isLoggedIn and also setLoggedIn in Login page.